# Highcharts: Area chart: fill in space between 0 and first point

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielesandoval/efHq7/

Is there a way to fill in the gap between the y-axis and the first point. The first point on my chart should be "25 years" and i would like the area between 0 and 25 to be filled in as well.  Even if the tooltip doesn't work for that point, I would just like to visually show that the values between 0 and the first point.

I tried adding a point with a x value of zero but that didnt work. The only area charts I have seen where there is no gap between the two axis and the area are examples where the chart is inverted. Is there a proper way to do this?

[image]

Current Code:

```
        $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Comparison'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '1 vs 2'
    },
    xAxis: {
         min: 0,
        categories: [0, '25 years', '30 years', '35 years', '40 years', '45 years']
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
            return '$' + this.value;
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Cost'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valuePrefix: '$'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
            enabled: false
            },
            shadow: false,
            states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'series1',
        data: [['',60],['25 years',60], ['30 years',60], ['35 years',60], ['40 years',60], ['45 years',60]]
        }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'series2',
        data: [['',90], ['25 years',100], ['30 years',175], ['35 years',300], ['40 years',400], ['45 years',400]]
    }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set minPadding/maxPadding as 0, but these parameters doesn't work with categories. So you need to use numeric xAxis, instead of categories.